# Can MS Notepad be used to create a relational database for web site integration?

Tags: database, web

#### **Situation:**

I am one of those individuals who enjoys learning to build everything in *Notepad*. I use Visual Studio, Eclipse, Sublime, SQL Server, etc. as well, but find that Notepad development offers a level of mastery and craftsmanship to the skill-set, i.e. tracking bugs without compilation assistance, intellisense dependency, etc.. My overall *personal* goal is to have the ability to develop an entire business-level web service using nothing more than a standard text editor. At this time, I can expertly do HTML5/CSS3/Javascript and graphics via canvas/SVG completely from memory, but now it's time for the back-end Asp.net/MVC & database learning. I know C#, T-SQL and RDB Design, but only from Visual Studio side.

#### **Question:**

Can a fully-functional RDB be created manually in MS Notepad via the CREATE TABLE syntax, stored on the server, and integrated into a website as a dynamic system? Note that I am not referring to the use of a CSV file, but rather hand coding the tables, attributes, relationships, etc. and running queries. I realize no one does this anymore, hence I can't locate an answer on Google, but if there are any old-school DB/back-end developers in here who can offer up insight, I would grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes at the end of the day everything in a relational database can be created from a text editor. There are no 'missing' commands that can't be used to create entire schemas and even populate the data from a plain SQL text file.

Comment: Any guidance on reference material for implementing this? By that I mean, do I create 1 notepad file for all tables, or 1 file for each table? Will SQL statements be handled via front-end/JavaScript and passed to the DB file or are SQL statements handled using Asp.Net - C#? I am kinda looking for someone who has done this before. Not  making assumptions that you haven't, no disrespect intended, I just realize this question is a bit off-the-shelf and may be difficult to answer. I don't need details, just a high-level overview so I can break up the research.

Comment: You can create a database of any size / amount of tables (I guess within notepad size limits) as a single text file. Asp.Net / C# / JS is all text at the end of the day as well. Be aware though some of the code is very verbose, I just opened the dataset for a .NET project and while large (close to 100 tables) it had over 125,000 lines of code that had been auto-generated for me. I still do most HTML and smaller critical piece of code by hand though. None of it will be linked automatically doing it that way, it'll be a huge undertaking in .NET.

Comment: Just as another addition, I'm old school too and like the notepad way. I still try to do most things by hand, especially for performance, but really some of the modern tools save so much time and tedium I use a combination of both ways as appropriate. Things like SQL Management studio let you quickly setup a database and you can still tweak anything later by SQL.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I agree completely, Notepad is not practical for a development environment. It is great for gaining proficiency though. Cheers.